# Noise during hard braking

Tags: honda, brakes, noise, civic

Today due to some emergency situation I applied very hard brake on my 2018 Honda Civic and it made a very loud sound as something got broken and car freeze .. after 2 min it started working.. Did anything happen to my car or brake system?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I would strongly suspect that's ABS, like @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 already suggested in an answer, but it would help a lot in providing an authoritative answer if you could [Edit] your question to describe the noise in more detail.

Answer (score 6):

Other than some excessive wear/tear on your brakes? Most likely not. Brakes are made to take some abuse. More than likely the ABS kicked in and was the noise you heard. They can sometimes seem a little funky right afterwards. If it is working fine right now, you probably aren't experiencing any issues. If you are truly worried about it, take it in to a Honda service center and have them take a look at it. I'll ***assume*** your car is still under warranty, seeing as how it's only a 2018, though it might have high mileage.